# C++ vectors, variable representation in memory, const char *

Tags: c++, parsing, vector

This piece of code is supposed to parse requests, extracts the URI path, then extract each individual header and its value then pass all those extracted variables into `std::vector <const char*> cva` which will be ultimately passed to `std::vector<std::vector<const char*>> nv  (config.nv.push_back(std::move(cva));)`

**I have few problems here:**

- It seems that the parsing is happening correctly but the way I am storing/passing the content of extracted variable is not working properly either due to a misunderstanding of how variables are stored/retrieved and their scope in C++ (most likely since I barely started learning C++) or some bigger issue that I am not aware of.
- I have inserted some `print` statements which show that my parsing has been done correctly.
- However the `for` loops (at the end) have different output then expected.   Here I had gone through another issue which is `cva.push_back(nullptr)`, if I keep this statement, the `for` loop prints the first element and then exits however when I remove that statement, it works fine. Why?

I would appreciate any help especially that I am hoping to learn more about C++ but it seems I am stumbling through a way too advanced issue

```
// I already have a reqlines vector<std::string> variable holding my requests
// each request is formed as follows 
// http://<hostname>:<portnumber>/path<TAB>header1:value1<TAB>header2:value2<TAB>header3:tab3<TAB>header4:tab4<etc.....>
// Pretty much a TAB separated string with request at beginning followed by extra headers

   std::vector<std::string> paths;
   std::vector<std::string> extraheaders;
   std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> tokenized;
   int count = 0;   // keeps track of each request number so I can access its corresponding extra headers from extraheaders vector

   if (condition is met){

        // creating which will be used to store my requests paths as well as extra headers
        // This has to be a const char * vector since it will be used by an external library which requires such type
        std::vector<const char *> cva;

        for (auto &req : reqlines){
                unsigned int pos = req.find_first_of("\t", 0);
                if (pos == -1){
                        paths.push_back(req);
                        extraheaders.push_back(" ");
                } else {
                        paths.push_back(req.substr(0, pos));
                        extraheaders.push_back(req.substr(pos+1, std::string::npos));
                }
        }

        for (auto &path : paths){
                cva.push_back(":path");
                cva.push_back(path.c_str()); // adding the URI path into cva variable  

                // explode function which returns a std::vector<std::string> when passing an std::string to it
                tokenized.push_back(explode(extraheaders[count], '      '));  // extracting the vector<std::string> of all extra headers

        //      if (tokenized[count][0].compare(" ") == 0){
        //              printf("   %d   element is empty is skipped  \n");
        //      }else { 

                for (auto &tok : tokenized[count]){   // looping through extra headers of request number "count", parsing header name/value and adding it to cva
                    printf(" %d   tok  %s\n", __LINE__, tok.c_str());
                    printf(" %d   tok address    %d\n", __LINE__, &tok);
                    unsigned int pos = tok.find_first_of(":", 0);
                    if (pos == -1 )
                        printf("  %d  there are no headers \n", __LINE__);
                    else {
                        printf("header name:   %s\n", (tok.substr(0, pos)).c_str());
                        printf("header value:   %s\n", (tok.substr(pos+1, std::string::npos)).c_str());
                        cva.push_back((tok.substr(0, pos)).c_str());
                        cva.push_back((tok.substr(pos+1, std::string::npos)).c_str());
                    }
                }
                cva.push_back(":version");  // adding version header
                cva.push_back("HTTP/1.1");  // adding version header number
                cva.push_back(nullptr);  // adding nullptr (which is how nv is expecting cva to be terminated)
                count++;

                // passing the cva content to nv 
                config.nv.push_back(std::move(cva));
        }

        // Below are the printing statement to check the values of the different variables I created and populated 
        // above, my problem is that the population process puts some values into my variables however printing
        // the content of the those variables shows different values from what I am expecting

                std::cout << "          " << std::endl << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Printing cva" << std::endl;
                for (auto &elem : cva){
                        std::cout << &elem << "   " <<elem << std::endl;
                }
                std::cout << "          " << std::endl << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Printing paths" << std::endl;
                for (auto &path : paths){
                        std::cout << &path << "    " << path << std::endl;
                }
                std::cout << "          " << std::endl << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Printing headers" << std::endl;
                for (auto &hed : extraheaders) {
                        std::cout << &hed << "    "<<hed << std::endl;
                }
}
```

---

Assuming I have a file which looks like this:

```
https://<endpoint>:<port>/path1
https://<endpoint>:<port>/path2<TAB>PCC:1234<TAB>Cookie:dsgfshg
https://<endpoint>:<port>/path3<TAB>PCC:5678
https://<endpoint>:<port>/path4
https://<endpoint>:<port>/path5
```

The expected output should be:

```
Printing cva
:path  
path1  
:path  
path2  
:PCC  
1234  
:Cookie  
dsgfshg  
:path  
path3  
:PCC  
5678  
:path  
path4  
:path  
path5
```

But the actual output is:

```
Printing cva
:path  
path1  
:path  
path2
:PCC  
5678  //Different - Wrong value
      //Different - Cookie + value is missing
:path  
path3  
:PCC  
5678  
:path  
path4  
:path  
path5
```

*Note: Printing `headers` and `path` are missing because they are the same*

Comment: "is not working properly" and "// WORNG" are not useful problem descriptions, and carry absolutely zero meaning, by themselves. Additionally, code examples on stackoverflow.com must consist of a [mcve]. This code example fails the "complete" requirement.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I actually gave the snippet of the code as well as example of the output both expected and actual output. The problem might be more conceptual, i.e the understanding of variables in C++, how they're handled in memory and their scope, lifetime. It could be just a minor tweak to fix it but also it might require way more advanced changes and that's what I am trying to know

Comment: Once again: this code example fails the "complete" requirement of a "[mcve]". Do you know what "complete" means? It means you can take the code, compile it, and run it, in order to reproduce the problem. Not the case here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I agree with you, the code is not complete and can't be compiled/run by anyone. Hence I have made it run (out of its bigger context) however I am not able to update this thread since someone has edited and it seems I lost control over it.